# Unable to locate the Java Uno RunTime (jurt) sources

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, openoffice.org

Actually I'm debugging a project that uses JodConverter as a third party dependency and so some Apache OpenOffice libraries such as Java Uno RunTime **jurt-3.2.1.jar**.

I'm not able to find the sources jar for these library when googling it, what I'm only able to reach is th [svn location for the OpenOffice project](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/ooo/trunk/main/jurt/). 
So can someone point me out to the jurt sources location?

Is there some trick to build the sources jar from this project **Or** make my IDE to point to a file or folder instead of a sources jar?
(I'm working on an Intellij IDEA in case it makes any difference)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `Project Settings` → `Libraries` → Find the library to add the sources for → Press on a plus sign (`"Add"`) → `Attach files or directories`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Vic . It really helped out.